# Google rank website worse with more specific matching text

Tags: seo

I have been reading a bit up on how Google rank sites. Specifically the things that affect rank other than the biggest one (i.e. who links to you, and how much weight do they carry through others linking to them). So that leaves content, structure, title, url, correct meta information and so on. I have been playing a bit around with these things, and this one thing, in particular, bugs me:

Website XX contains the exact text "foo bar bazet". If I search for "foo bar baz" XX shows up as item #3 on page #1, but if I search for "foo bar bazet" (now with the surfix "et") then XX ends up as item #8 on page #3. Almost all of the sites that through this change in query is ranked better doesn't actually contain the exact text "foo bar bazet", so how come they suddenly get a higher rank than XX? If anything shouldn't XX benefit from this?

I am fully aware that there are very good reasons for this. I just want to know what they are.

Comment: This can happen based upon search history and as in your case, bazet may not have much search history to rank the term. Ranking search terms is a multi-part process, one of which is search history and click-through rate (CTR) of the results. For example, a search for bazet gives links for baz and the CTR is good for baz historically, then Google may think you mean baz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You needn't to use exact match keyword to rank well for it in serps. Research more informations about "cocitation" and how SE or other machine learning systems use semantic to forecast intents or to rank sth.